# Как вернуть значение переменной из функции

Tags: powershell

```
$so='';
function Get-Dirr {
$so=(Get-ChildItem "C:\Windows\System32" | Select FullName).FullName
}

Get-Dirr
$so.count
```

переменная so возвращается пустой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если собираетесь модифицировать глобальную переменную, то надо писать `$global:so=`, а если возвращать значение, то `$so=` вообще не нужно, так как функция будет возвращать результат последнего выражения, только результат вызова надо потом не игнорировать.

Comment: это вариант. Постараюсь объяснить. Я впервые знакомлюсь с функциями. Смысл в том что мне надо несколько раз использовать фрагмент кода (функцию). Так вот, содержимое директории поменяется при последующем использовании функции, и следовательно переменная so должна будет содержать уже другой список файлов на основании чего сработает другая логика. Я пока не могу логически понять:). Мне не надо что бы выводился результат функции, мне надо что бы $so каждый раз обновлялась.

Comment: у меня внутри функции на самом деле сложнее, но мне важно понять на этом простом примере - как при каждом использовании моей пользовательской функции, результат записывался в переменную so и  я потом мог вытащить её в любом месте скрипта.

Comment: Сработало!, я внутри функции поставил $global:so=(Get-ChildItem "C:\Windows\System32" | Select FullName).FullName и вытащил результат за пределами функции - то что мне и нужно было. Гениально ))

Comment: Почему про это нигде не пишут, я неск часов пролазил в интернете )))

Comment: @Oleg0341 Как ни странно, это все написано непосредственно во встроенной справке powershell. `get-help about_scopes`